# Reseed back 1 with existing data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity-column

I have a table with alot of missing identity ids missing.  I would also like to start it back at 1 with.

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('Customer', RESEED, 0)
```

However, there is existing data in the table, so will this effect anything?

Say I have ID 2,3,5 in the table with 1 and 4 gone.  If I execute the SQL above, does that start the next new row in that table at 1, then the next at 4 without bothering 2,3,5 and so on?

Comment: No, see the section: **Changing the seed value** here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESEEDING to 0 on table with existing data will cause duplicates of existing ID or raise error when Unique Constraints is available. Please see POC for further clarification of the same
**TestData:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'Table1') > 0
    BEGIN
       DROP TABLE Table1
    END

CREATE TABLE Table1 (ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
                 Col1 VARCHAR(3))

INSERT INTO Table1
VALUES('1F'),('3A'),('2A'),('4G'),('5X')

SELECT * FROM Table1

DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE ID IN( 2, 4)

SELECT * FROM Table1

DBCC CHECKIDENT('Table1', RESEED, 0)

INSERT INTO Table1
VALUES ('12F'),('34A'),('23A'),('45G'),('56X')

SELECT *
FROM Table1

DELETE FROM Table1

DBCC CHECKIDENT('Table1', RESEED, 0)

ALTER TABLE Table1
ADD UNIQUE (Id)

INSERT INTO Table1
VALUES('1F'),('3A'),('2A'),('4G'),('5X')

SELECT * FROM Table1

DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE ID IN( 2, 4)

DBCC CHECKIDENT('Table1', RESEED, 0)

SELECT * FROM Table1

INSERT INTO Table1
VALUES ('12F'),('34A'),('23A'),('45G'),('56X')

IF OBJECT_ID(N'Table1') > 0
    BEGIN
       DROP TABLE Table1
    END
IF OBJECT_ID(N'Table1') > 0
    BEGIN
       DROP TABLE Table1
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

Any attempt to reseed an identity column with a value that is less than the maximum value in the identity column will generate an error if the column is set to  be unique (primary key or unique constraint). If the column is not set to be unique, then the command will execute as expected, but you will get duplicate values as you come across those ID's again. In other words, it will not skip 2, 3, and 5 in your example. [See this link for more detail](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258817(v=sql.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Although missing ids are not aesthetically pleasing to the eye, they make absolutely no difference to the database performance.

If you are using these values to display something like a Customer Ref to the user, then you should use a separate field for this. Database IDs should not be relied upon for display, as the rules for your database, may differ from your rules for your Customer Ref etc.

I would suggest if this is your problem that you add an additional field for the Customer Ref - populate it with the current Database Id for default values, then you can do whatever you want to this new field (as far as ensuring that all values are used sequentially) without interfering with the performance and integrity of the database.

Answer (score 0):

Create a BackUp table:

```
Create table [dbo].[personbkp](
[Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
[name] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
)
```

Select Into Statement to save data :

```
SELECT p.name
INTO dbo.personbkp
FROM person p 
GO
```

Clean Table:

```
DELETE FROM person
```

Reseed:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('person', RESEED, 0)
```

Use BackUp:

```
SELECT bk.name
INTO dbo.person
FROM personbkp
```

Drop BackUp table:

```
DROP TABLE dbo.personbkp
```